# How to disable transaction wrapping for a migration in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

The situation I am in calls for a migration that cannot be ran within a transaction and must be ran as a query. So far, we have been running migrations in this format with success:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class migrationNameXXXXXXXXXXX implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`

      // SQL code in here...

      `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}
}
```

The problem arises when using queryRunner because it wraps any query inside a transaction. Is there any way to disable the transaction wrapping?

I have searched and [found saveOptions inside the repository section, which has a "transaction" boolean variable.](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/SaveOptions.ts) But I have not been able to leverage that into the useable result.

Answer (score 2):

Weird...
I run my SQL directly through the DataSource like this `await DataSource.query(query, params);` and it won't start a transaction unless I invoke it through `BEGIN TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT TRANSACTION;` You can turn on the TypeORM logger and see all the queries that are run to validate.

The `SaveOptions.transaction` option is only for managed entities. It can be invoked like this `await DataSource.manager.save(ManagedEntity, { transaction: false });`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to migration file and use DataSource connection manager instead of the provided queryRunner:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class migrationNameXXXXXXXXXXX implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(_queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    const queryRunner = dataSource.manager;
    await queryRunner.query(`

      // SQL code in here...

      `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}
}
```

2. Run migration with `-t each` option

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:run -t each
```